# Calling a shared library function from Python hangs (possible thread / interrupt issue)

Tags: python, multithreading, shared-libraries, deadlock, ctypes

I have a problem with a shared library function called from Python.

Consider this simplified C program that acquires an image from a camera:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include <someproprietarylibraryheader.h>

int myfunction() {
    CameraHandle handle;

    printf("Running... \n");

    if(!camera_init(&handle) {     // initialize the camera handle
        return -1;
    }

    if(!camera_precapture(handle)) {   // prepare for capture
        printf("ERROR precapture\n");
        return -1;
    }
    else {
        printf("precapture OK\n");
    }

    if(!camera_capture(handle)) {  // start frame capture (returns immediately)
        printf("ERROR capture\n");
        return -1;
    }
    else {
        printf("capture OK\n");
    }

    if(!camera_wait(handle)) {     // wait for capture to be completed   
        printf("ERROR wait\n");
        return -1;
    }
    else {
        printf("wait OK\n");
    }

    if(!camera_close(handle)) {    // close the camera
        printf("ERROR close\n");
        return -1;
    }

    printf("Done!!\n");

    return 0;
}
```

If I compile this code into a shared library and call `myfunction()` from a C program linking to it, **everything works as expected**.

However, consider what happens if one loads the libray and calls `myfunction()` from Python like this:

```
from ctypes import *

mylib = cdll.LoadLibrary("mylib.so")
mylib.myfunction()
```

In this case the program hangs indefinitely at the line `camera_capture()` in the C code. However, something interesting happens by sending a `KeyboardInterrupt` with `CTRL+C`: just before this exception is handled by the interpreter, the program is able to resume and `myfunction()` continues and terminates normally.

This looks like a hung thread. Indeed by running the above Python script with `gdb`, I have found out that the proprietary camera API does create some threads. And by examining the backtrace, the program seems to be stuck at a call to `nanosleep()` somewhere within the proprietary code. Apparently, the `nanosleep()` function is not properly interrupted, but only when run in Python.

Another hint that this is a thread / interrupt issue is the fact that if I run the Python script in `gdb`, I can do `CTRL+C` followed by `continue` indefinitely at the point where the program hangs. However, if I place a breakpoint with `b` and then `continue`, the program resumes and terminates correctly.

Does anybody have a clue about what might prevent this simple program to run smoothly when called from Python, and why don't the threads created by the C library terminate properly when run from Python? Thanks a lot.

Comment: What's the expected behavior? How long does it take to complete? What does it capture? A frame, a movie? So the last text that you see when running from *Python* is "*precapture OK*"?

Comment: In this configuration it captures a single frame. Normally, camera initialization takes around 5 seconds, and capturing is almost instantaneous. Yes, when running from Python the last thing I see is _"precapture OK"_, but if I hit `CTRL+C` the program resumes normally all the way down to printing _"Done!!"_